# How can I import an SVG file in R ?

Tags: r, svg

I have a map of France with the contour of French departments in an SVG file. I would like to import the data in R to draw a choropleth map. Is it possible ? What would be the best solution ?

Comment: the `grImport`/`grConvert` packages claim to be able to import SVG files. Whether that gives a format suitable for creating a choropleth, I don't know.

Comment: Indeed, it can be down with `grImport` as long as the SVG is first converted to Postscript. See https://github.com/jsta/sfpolymorph/blob/master/data-raw/sheep.R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `SVGMapping::loadSVG`  (at CRAN)  -- I haven't tried it so can't speak to its quality.

Edit: might as well mention the `sos` package here, as it's really an indispensable tool for finding `R` packages and functions for the user.

Comment: SVGMapping is not available for R 3.0.2

Comment: @PAC bummer - maybe it'll build from source?

Comment: @PAC  Can you pick your preferred answer & check it off?  Thanks.

Comment: There is no SVGmapping package on CRAN main now, source or otherwise. Probably orphaned in the archive... http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SVGMapping/ and it doesn't let you plot SVGs in general anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is possible. SVG is nothing more than a XML document. But why don't you use `maps` library?

```
library(maps)
map('france')
```

You can check:

```
>  map('france')$names
[1] "Nord"                                
[2] "Pas-de-Calais"                       
[3] "Somme"
...
```

for departments names, and paint individual departments like this:

```
colors[c(112, 114)] <- 'blue'
map('france', fill=T, col=colors)
```

[image]

See [maps documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/maps.pdf) for more.